# Organizing Results in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, organization

Alright, so basically I have a Google script that searches for a keyword.  The results look like:

```
    http://www.example.com/user/1234
    http://www.youtube.com/user/125
    http://www.forum.com/user/12
```

What could I do to organize these results like this?:

```
    Forums:
    http://www.forum.com/user/12

    YouTubes:
    http://www.youtube.com/user/125

    Unidentified:
    http://www.example.com/user/1234
```

By the way I'm organizing them with keywords. If the url has "forum" in it then it goes to the forum list, if it has YouTube it goes to the YouTube list, but if no keywords match up then it goes to unidentified.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are both input and output strings? What are your rules of organizing things? By domain? Why is `example.com` unidentified? And finally: what have you tried?

Comment: I'm organizing them with keywords.  If the url has "forum" in it then it goes to the forum list, if it has youtube it goes to the youtube list, but if no keywords match up then it goes to unidentified.

Comment: Did you try to solve this by yourself in any fashion?

Comment: Yes, but I was using bash the run the Python script, then trying to organize the results with grep, sed, etc.  All tries have failed, lol.  I have no idea how I would solely go about doing this in Python.

Comment: What happens when a URL contains both "forum" and "youtube"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? I guess you will be able to adapt this example to your needs

```
import pprint
import re

urls = ['http://www.example.com/user/1234',
        'http://www.youtube.com/user/126',
        'http://www.youtube.com/user/125',
        'http://www.forum.com/useryoutube/12'] 

pattern = re.compile('//www\.(\w+)\.')

keys = ['forum', 'youtube']
results = dict()

for u in urls:
    ms = pattern.search(u)
    key = ms.group(1)
    if key in keys:
        results.setdefault(key, []).append(u)

pprint.pprint(results)
```

Comment: it will better not to hardcoded the key, it should generate dynamically and create the key, as he doesn't know what are all the domain name or key in advanced.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks. I edited my post. I gave the OP the possibility to select the keys he's interested in.

Comment: and now with a more solid pattern matching so that the last url is classified as forum

Answer (score 2):

1/. Create a `dict`, and assign an empty list to each keyword you have.
eg
 `my_dict = {'forums':[],'youtube':[],'unidentified':[]}`

2/.Iterate over your urls.

3/. Generate a key for your url,domain name in your case, you can extract the key using `re` regex module.

4/ Check the dictionary ( of step#1) for this key, if it does not exist, assign it to 'unidentified key, if it exists, append this url to the list in the dictionary with that key.

Comment: I don't think he always wants the domain name to be the key. For instance, the key of `example.com` is "Unidentified".

Answer (score 1):

```
import urlparse

urls = """
http://www.example.com/user/1234
http://www.youtube.com/user/125
http://www.forum.com/user/12
""".split()

categories = {
    "youtube.com": [],
    "forum.com": [],
    "unknown": [],
}

for url in urls:
    netloc = urlparse.urlparse(url).netloc
    if netloc.count(".") == 2:
        # chop sub-domain
        netloc = netloc.split(".", 1)[1]
    if netloc in categories:
        categories[netloc].append(url)
    else:
        categories["unknown"].append(url)
print categories
```

Parse the urls. Find the category. Append the full url

Answer (score 1):

You should probably keep your sorted results in a dictionary and the unsorted ones in a list. You could then sort it like so:

```
categorized_results = {"forum": [], "youtube": []}
uncategorized_results = []
for i in results:
    i = i.split(".")
    for k in categorized_results:
        j = True
        if k in i:
            categorized_results[k].append(i)
            j = False
        if j:
            uncategorized_results.append(i)
```

If you'd like to output it neatly:

```
category_aliases: {"forum": "Forums:", "youtube": "Youtubes:"}
for i in categorized_results:
    print(category_aliases[i])
    for j in categorized_results[i]:
        print(j)
    print("\n")
print("Unidentified:")
print("\n".join(uncategorized_results)) # Let's not put in another for loop.
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
from urlparse import urlparse

class Organizing_Results(object):

    CATEGORY = {'example': [], 'youtube': [], 'forum': []}

    def __init__(self):
        self.url_list = []

    def add_single_url(self, url):
        self.url_list.append(urlparse(url))

    def _reduce_result_list(self, acc, element):
        for c in self.CATEGORY:
            if c in element[1]:
                return self.CATEGORY[c].append(element)
        return self.CATEGORY['example'].append(element)

    def get_result(self):
        reduce(lambda x, y: c._reduce_result_list(x, y), c.url_list, [])
        return self.CATEGORY

c = Organizing_Results()          
c.add_single_url('http://www.example.com/user/1234')
c.add_single_url('http://www.youtube.com/user/1234')
c.add_single_url('http://www.unidentified.com/user/1234')
c.get_result()
```

You can easy broaden the class with more functions as you need.